# How to save handlebar registry for future use

Tags: rust, template-engine

I'm using the [handlebars](https://docs.rs/crate/handlebars/4.3.6) temlate engine. The handlebar registry is initialized as usual:

```
let mut registry = Handlebars::new();
```

and I want to save this handlebar registry as a member of a struct for future use:

```
struct AppState {
    pool: Pool,
    registry : handlebars::registry::Registry,
}
```

however the `handlebars::registry` module is private, so I can't do that. What should I do?

**Update:**

I tried using the struct name `Handlebar`:

```
struct AppState {
    pool: Pool,
    registry: Handlebars,
}
```

But the compiler says:

> missing lifetime specifier
> expected named lifetime parameter

As I'm quite new to lifetime semantics in rust, the following modification fails(compiler still says "missing lifetime specifier
/expected named lifetime parameter"):

```
struct AppState<'a> {
    pool: Pool,
    registry: &'a Handlebars,
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to avoid the public name for it [`handlebars::Handlebars`](https://docs.rs/handlebars/latest/src/handlebars/lib.rs.html#398)?

Comment: @cafce25 thanks for the guide, question updated.

Comment: Read the full error message from rust. [It tells you how to add the lifetime](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=387d71be99c6968b02a71fc60f516b04). Also I feel a maximum of 22mins is maybe not really enough time to research a problem properly before updating/posting a question with more problems, as [ask] suggests.

Comment: @cafce25 thanks so much for the advice, the modification above was my attempt I made before I post this SO question. Maybe I need to learn more about the lifetime concepts in rust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however the handlebars::registry module is private, so I can't do
> that. What should I do?

The public alias for Registry is `Handlebars`.
You will find the following statement in `lib.rs`

```
pub use self::registry::{html_escape, no_escape, EscapeFn, Registry as Handlebars};
```

On the other hand `Handlebars` requires lifetime argument, your can use it the following way:

```
use handlebars::Handlebars;

struct AppState<'a> {
    registry: Handlebars<'a>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut registry = Handlebars::new();
    let app = AppState { registry };
}
```

If you want a `static` reference, which will remain for the entire lifetime of the running program. Replace `<'a>` with `<'static>` and you should not specify the lifetime parameter name for the struct like follows:

```
use handlebars::Handlebars;

struct AppState {
    registry: Handlebars<'static>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut registry = Handlebars::new();
    let app = AppState { registry };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just specify `'static`:

```rust
struct AppState {
    pool: Pool,
    registry: handlebars::Handlebars<'static>,
}
```